# Makefile compile single file using Python

Tags: python, makefile

I'm migrating from Pythone 2.x to 3.x. And I'm trying to compile single file in Makefile using Python:

From the Makefile:

```
mySuperFile.c :  $(ROOT)/lib/mySuperFileGenerate $(FILES_DIR) $(REPO_STATE_FILE)
$(ROOT)/lib/mySuperFileGenerate --out-dir=$(OUT_DIR) --repo=$(ROOT) --output=mySuperFile.c
```

Where **mySuperFileGenerate** is the Python script, that says to use global python version, which is 2.x.x and does not satisfy me:

```
!/usr/bin/env python
```

That's why I want to call Python version explicitly, like this (added ${PYTHON373} variable before script):

```
mySuperFile.c : ${PYTHON373} $(ROOT)/lib/mySuperFileGenerate $(FILES_DIR) $(REPO_STATE_FILE)
     $(ROOT)/lib/mySuperFileGenerate --out-dir=$(OUT_DIR) --repo=$(ROOT) --output=mySuperFile.c
```

But it does not work at all. It still calls the version from environment - 2.x.

**So my question is:**

How to specify which Python to use exactly in Makefile? (Not changing environment). Is it possible?

Comment: You *have* to change the environment (since that's what `env` uses, specifically the value of `PATH`, to determine which `python` to run), or you  need to modify the shebang in `mySuperFileGenerate` to use the correct interpreter.

Comment: Yes, this may be the solution. But actually I can't change it. This is a global env, I do not have access privileges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line in your rule describes the *prerequisites* of the target.  It doesn't describe how to *run* the target.  All adding `${PYTHON373}` to that line does is say that if that file changes, the target should be rebuilt.

The second line (indented by a TAB) in your rule shows how to run the command.  If you want to run the command using a different Python interpreter you have to add it to the command to be run:

```
mySuperFile.c : ${PYTHON373} $(ROOT)/lib/mySuperFileGenerate $(FILES_DIR) $(REPO_STATE_FILE)
         $(PYTHON373) $(ROOT)/lib/mySuperFileGenerate --out-dir=$(OUT_DIR) --repo=$(ROOT) --output=mySuperFile.c
```

Comment: Really it works now! I just added ${PYTHON373} only to one line.
And thanks a lot for the explanation!